# CSS: Is there a way to make an element fill the page?

Tags: html, css, height

If I have the following code, how can I make the second div take up the rest of the page?:

```
<div style="height:300px;">
  blah
</div>

<div style="?">

</div>
```

For example, if the user's browser window's height is 1000px, then how can I make the second div 700px?

Comment: What do you want the second div for? Just asking as there might be a better way to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If absolute positioning is not a problem, you can do it like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height:300px; background-color:yellow;">
    Foo
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: red;">
    Bar
</div>
```

Comment: I did it this way, but I'm afraid it might not work well in all browsers. So far it's not working in IE, but it's the best one here, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach you could take:

1. Make the first `<div>` a child of the second `<div>`
2. Give the outer `<div>` some padding equal to the height of the inner `<div>`
3. Use `position: absolute;` to get the inner `<div>` snapping to the top of the page

Now the outer `<div>` will act as the bottom `<div>`.

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#outer
    {
        padding-top: 300px;
    }

    div#inner
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        background: yellow;
        display: block;
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        top content
    </div>

    bottom content
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Eq8Jq/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use on div2 `style = "height: 100%"`. However, this only works if the container also has a height specified. If this is just in your main body then set `body { height: 100%; }` also

Answer (score 0):

The key is style="height:100%" for the second div as mentioned by mrtsherman.

```
<div style="height:300px;background-color:yellow">
    blah
</div>

<div style="clear:both;height:100%;background-color:red;">
    Second div
</div>
```

The second div will have red BG for the rest of the page.

If this is not what you want, let us know.

Comment: Right, there's no table. But your styles will work only when it is applied to a table.

Comment: Where are you getting that from? Try it out. It seems working at least on my FF5. You can apply styles to div. Not sure how can the styles of a div depend on a table? Could you please explain how the style of a div(s) can depend on table???

Comment: A div height depends on the content. If div is empty and has "height: 100%;" it height will be 0. The only exception - absolutely positioned divs. But they are not good for making general site structure in most cases. P.S. Add your code to jsfiddle - you'll see.

Comment: jsfiddle has different behavior than what I see on my test site